# Rust: How do you pass an Option<trait> as a function parameter?

Tags: arguments, rust, traits, boxing

I keep getting "Sized is not implemented". How do I get wp into the function foo? I thought boxing would give it a size, but I get the same error with or without it.

```
fn main() {
    let wp : Option<Waypoint>= new(45.1968, -75.1968);
    foo(box wp);
}

fn foo(wp: Box<Option<Coord>>) {
    println!("lat: {}, lon:{}", wp.lat(), wp.lon());
}
```

[full code](http://is.gd/sNTnk1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Option<Box<Coord>>` instead. `Box<T>` is able to take unsized data, but `Option` isn't.

You can only use unsized types through references, and can't directly handle instances of them. (Rust needs to know the size of data on the stack at all times)